# error while running a bat file , i want to run it daily

Tags: python, cmd

i created a bat file to execute my python script daily, however while im running the file im getting an error , im not an expert and dont have any experience in command prompt or creating executable file

below is my bat file details which i wrote on notepad and saved it as .bat

```
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe "C:\Users\RT00000\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\SalesforceAutomatedCode2.py"
pause
```

and im getting this error

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: ``C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe`` -> ``"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"``

Comment: i tried that i got another error ``` C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\RTambe00000\\Desktop\\python basics\\web scraping\\salceforce code\\SalesforceAutomatedCode2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory ```

Comment: I see difference: RT00000 -> RTambe00000. Does this path exist in your environment?

Comment: @Rohantambe And you are sure that this path exists and is accessible? Can you prove it? This "...salceforce code..." looks pretty much like a typo, at least I would have expected "...salesforce code...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quote if there is a space in a path

```
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users\RT00000\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\SalesforceAutomatedCode2.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users\RT00000\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\SalesforceAutomatedCode2.py"
```

Comment: brother thanks for the reply , i tried your way i still got the error  C:\Users\RTambe00000\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code>C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe C:\Users\RTambe00000\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\salceforce code\SalesforceAutomatedCode2.py
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @yangjiang You totally missed the point that there are spaces in the folder names.

Comment: I found your question and revised the answer